# Is it possible to merge cells of different rows e.g. A1:C2 using Excel JS Api?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am able to merge cells of the same row using Excel JS Api like this

```
let B2F2cellRange = sheet.getRange("B2:F2");
B2F2cellRange.merge(true);
```

But once I try to merge an area like this: sheet.getRange("B2:F3") it fails.
Any idea? Is it a limitation of the Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 behaviors for this API. I guess you may want to try`range.merge(false)` behavior:

1. range.merge(false)

[image]

2. range.merge(true)

[image]

The doc can be found at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#merge-across-

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the error is when you failed to merge an area like sheet.getRange("B2:F3"). I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/xiaochunms/977622226b82e379ce77c757fe19798d) to perform the same operation, which works for me. You may can have a try then.